# Bash programming if instruction doesn't work

Tags: bash

I´m trying to make a little bash program in order to control my light via a 433Mhz transmitter, but my if clause in my programm doesn´t work.

Programm:

```
    #!/bin/sh -x

    if [ "$1"="A" ]; then
            if [ "$2"="off" ] || [ "$2"="0" ] || [ "$2"="OFF" ] ;then
                    /opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 1364
            else
                    /opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 1361
            fi
    fi
```

output:

```
    + [ B=A ]
    + [ Lol=off ]
    + /opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 1364
    sending code[1364]
```

Does anyone has an advice?

Comment: [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) automatically detects issues like this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems incorrect.

```
if [ "$2"="off" ] || [ "$2"="0" ] || [ "$2"="OFF" ] ;then
```

The following will be correct.

```
if [ "$2" = "off" ] || [ "$2" = "0" ] || [ "$2" = "OFF" ] ;then
```

(same to `if [ "$1"="A" ]; then`)

---

`[ "$2" = "off" ]` is equivalent to `test "$2" = "off"`, which give 3 arguments to test command.

However `test "off"="on"` is true, which give 1 argument to test command.

Answer (score 1):

As [set0gut1 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50424641/931027), the issue is the lack of spaces round the `=` in the tests.  A string like `"$1"="A"` is always *true* regardless of the value of `$1`.

Suggestion for neater code:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

if [ "$1" = "A" ]; then
    case "$2" in
        off|OFF|0) /opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 1364 ;;
        *)         /opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 1361 ;;
    esac
fi
```

or, for a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) variation,

```
#!/bin/sh -x

if [ "$1" = "A" ]; then
    case "$2" in
        off|OFF|0) arg=1364 ;;
        *)         arg=1361 ;;
    esac
    /opt/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend "$arg"
fi
```

or,

```
#!/bin/sh -x

PATH="/opt/433Utils/RPi_utils:$PATH"

if [ "$1" = "A" ]; then
    case "$2" in
        off|OFF|0) arg=1364 ;;
        *)         arg=1361 ;;
    esac
    codesend "$arg"
fi
```

... unless that interferes somehow with other utilities in the script.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I´ll try it out later looks a bit shorter :D